# Using Flask-SocketIO in conjunction with Flask-WTF / WTForms to provide realtime form validation feedback

Tags: python, html, flask, socket.io

I am working on a user login using Flask and the following extensions: `Flask-Login`, `Flask-WTF`, `WTForms` and `Flask-SocketIO`

**Client-Side**

Rendering of Forms and pre-filling with data is done with `Flask-WTF` / `WTForms` just like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="username-password-form" method="post" action="/settings/system/userpassword">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                {{ form.name(size=20, class_='form-control', placeholder='Username') }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                {{ form.password(size=20, class_='form-control', placeholder='Password') }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                {{ form.password_confirm(size=20, class_='form-control', placeholder='Retype Password') }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

**Server-Side (Python)**

In Python the responsible code for handling the Form is encapsulated in a Flask-Blueprint:

```
class UsernamePasswordForm(Form):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password_confirm = PasswordField('password_confirm', validators=[DataRequired()])

    def validate_on_submit(self):
        rv = Form.validate_on_submit(self)
        if not rv:
            return False
        # Validation not yet implemented ...
        return True


blueprint = Blueprint('settings_system', __name__)


@blueprint.route('/')
def settings_system():
    return render_template('settings-system.html')


@blueprint.route('/userpassword', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def set_username_password():
    form = UsernamePasswordForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        socket_io.emit('user_password_successfull', namespace='/test')
        return ('', 204)
    form.name.data = 'Current Name'
    return render_template('settings-system-username-password-modal.html', form=form)
```

**Socket-IO**

My intention was to give feedback right after the user has submitted the form back to the server. So instead of just responding with rendering of a template, I returned an empty response:

```
return ('', 204)
```

To feedback results to the browser / client I am using `Flask-SocketIO`. Just before returning an empty response, Socket-IO emits a message that the Form was validated.

```
socket_io.emit('user_password_successfull', namespace='/test')
```

On the Client side I am using this `Socket-IO` message to - for example - close a modal or let the user know that he has successfully entered the user information.

In case of wrong input or something went wrong during form validation I can emit a `Socket-IO` message which - for example - shows an error message or changes the `HTML` using `jQuery` so that the user directly knows which form-field was forcing that error, etc. For Exempel:

```
socket.on('user_password_successfull', function () {
                $( '#username-password-modal' ).modal('hide');
                swal("Good job!", "done", "success")
            });
```

Since these are still my first steps on Web-Applications, `jQuery`, `Socket-IO`, etc. I am really looking forward to get some feedback on my concept of handling real-time form validation feedback to the user.

Also let me know if there is something wrong with using classic Forms with `Socket-IO` realtime feedback on top!?